# Moving certain specific files from a folder structure to another with same directory structure

Tags: powershell, cmd, autohotkey

I have several thousands of image files (jpg, PNG, gif etc) inside many subfolders. Example

```
images\2018\jan\baba\hello1_abc.jpg
images\2018\jan\kaka\hello6_pqr.gif
images\2016\mar\baby\hello7_abc.png
images\2018\jan\yoga\hello3_xyz.jpg
images\2018\jan\yoga\hello345_abc.bmp
```

Etc etc

(ABC, pqr, XYZ are some 3 digit numbers denoting some file properties)

Now without disturbing the directory structure I want to move all the files containing `abc` in their name. Making it sorted by year, month, topic, and 'abc' 'xyz' 'pqr'. Like,

```
images\abc\2018\jan\baba\hello1_abc.jpg
images\abc\2016\mar\baby\hello7_abc.png
images\abc\2018\jan\yoga\hello345_abc.bmp
images\2018\jan\kaka\hello6_pqr.gif
images\2018\jan\yoga\hello3_xyz.jpg
```

Right now I use my manual method i.e.

1. I search for 'abc' in "C:\images".
2. Delete the resulted files containing 'abc' in their names. (Which moves them to recycle bin)
3. Rename the parent folder "images" into "images1".
4. Then restore the deleted files, which create automatically create the previous directory structure.
5. Then use "remove empty directory" software to delete any empty folders.

While this method works as I intend, it's very slow, because my collections of images exceed several thousands of images.
Searching, deleting and restoring them is time consuming.

I know this can be achieved using some script in either (does, powershell or auto hot key)(these are my favourite scripting language) but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example][https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]. You should research how to use  `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter ...` along with `Copy-Item`  to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
#Search query
$Query = [RegEx]'_abc$'

#Root of search and place for new structure.
$FileRoot = "C:\images\"

#Get all files in the desired structure that match your search query
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FileRoot -Recurse | Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Basename -match $Query }


foreach ($File in $Files) {
    #Generates a new path
    $NewPath = $FileRoot + $Query + "\"+ $File.DirectoryName.Replace("$FileRoot","")

    #Create the folder if it is not already created and move the item.
    New-Item -Path $NewPath -ItemType directory
    Move-Item -Path $File.Fullname -Destination $NewPath
}
```

I have done some light testing, but it may be that there are things I have not taken into consideration with your filestructure.

You could copy some of your folders into a test like c:\images1\ and then try to run the script in that folder. Just change the $FileRoot variable"

In order to choose which files you look for, change the $Query variable.

The result should be that all files that contains "ABC" will be moved to:

```
C:\images\abc\RestOfThePathTheItemHadBefore\file_abc.ext
```

Comment: As explained by OP `abc` are numbers at the end of the BaseName delimited with an underscore - your script doesn't take that into account. Your `$Query` could match at any point in $_.FullName. Change `$Query = [RegEx]'_abc$'` and `$_.Basename -match $Query`

Comment: Yeah I didn't think of that at all when I wrote it, might just have been a bit confused as to what OP ment. Thanks for the input! I have updated the script with your suggested regex and using the basename instead of the fullname

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply. It's exactly what I needed. The last 3 digit of the filename represents width or height of the image file. But sometimes those numbers are incorrect, is there a quick way to check the details/properties of the file so that I can find out its real width or height? Right now I use ImageMagick for that purpose. Please suggest any other quicker ways to do this cause I have got a lot of files to sort. Thank you again...